# Distribution of the product of Cauchy IID random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, fourier-analysis, characteristic-functions

Can anyone tell me if the product distribution of (say $n$) IID Cauchy random variables has a tractable form? And if so, what's a good way to go about deriving it? Characteristic functions (ie. Fourier transforms) perhaps? Or is there a simplification of the polynomial form?

Any thoughts are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Let $X,Y$ be iid Cauchy random variables. Then
$$
\mathbb P((X,Y)\in A)=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_{(x,y)\in A}\frac{dx\ dy}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}.
$$

Let $U=XY$. It follows that
$$
\mathbb P(U\in B)=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_{xy\in B}\frac{dx\ dy}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}.
$$
Let $u=xy$. For fixed $x>0$, we have $y=u/x$ and therefore $dy=du/x$. Since the distribution of $X$ is symmetric, we obtain
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(U\in B)&=
\frac{2}{\pi^2}\int_{u\in B}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx\ du/x}{(1+x^2)(1+(u/x)^2)}\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi^2}\int_{u\in B}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\ dx\ du}{(1+x^2)(x^2+u^2)}\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi^2}\int_{u\in B}\frac{1}{u^2-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^2}-\frac{x}{u^2+x^2}\ dx\ du\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_{u\in B}\frac{\log u^2}{u^2-1}\ du.
\end{align*}
$$

Therefore the density of $U$ is given by
$$
\frac{\log u^2}{\pi^2(u^2-1)}.
$$

Comment: great!do you have a reference for this proof?

Comment: The proof is original but any textbook on (multivariate) probability theory should have similar computations, a good reference is Durrett's book available at the author's website https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/pte5.html

Comment: Just in case you are looking for someting "citable", there is this: https://doi.org/10.2307/2313709