Ratio of two independent Cauchy distribution
We know that if $X\sim\text{Cauchy}(0,1)$ then $1/X\sim \text{Cauchy}$. Now consider two independent Cauchy distribution $X$ and $Y$, then what is the distribution of $X/Y$.
N.B. This question is due to out of curiosity, I did’t find any satisfactory answer to this question.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451720/distribution-of-the-product-of-cauchy-iid-random-variables may be useful, uses IID Cauchy rvs

@fGDu94 Think that’s just the answer, given the result about $1/X$ mentioned.

yes that is correct, this link gives the required RV

thanks for the reference @fGDu94.

Since the question linked by @fGDu94 gives the density for $U=XY$ as $\dfrac{\log(u^2)}{\pi^2(u^2-1)}$ and since $V=X/Y$ has the same density for the reciprocal reason given in the question, I will close this as a duplicate. Simulation confirms the result for both.
